# Closing Word application using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need help closing the Word app after its finished. Everything in the code runs fine except when it comes to closing the Word application. After running the code the edited document is saved and closed but the word application is still left open. This causes a problem as I need to run this code numerous times.

```
Sub ReplaceWordAndCopyPasteImage2()

    Dim wdApp       As Word.Application
    Dim Wks         As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc       As Word.Document

    Set Wks = ActiveSheet

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\SMS TEMPLATES\02 RISK ASSESSMENTS\002 Manual handling RA.docx")

    Call ReplaceWords2(wdDoc, Wks, False)
    Call CopyPasteImage2(wdDoc, Wks, False)      'switch back to true
    Call CloseWord2(wdDoc, Wks, False)

    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub

Sub ReplaceWords2(oDoc As Word.Document, Wks As Excel.Worksheet, Optional boolCloseAfterExec As Boolean = True)

    Dim wdRng       As Word.Range
    Dim varTxt      As Variant
    Dim varRngAddress As Variant
    Dim i           As Long

    varTxt = Split("an1,id1,rd1", ",")
    varRngAddress = Split("C8,C5,C6", ",")

    For Each wdRng In oDoc.StoryRanges

        With wdRng.Find
            For i = 0 To UBound(varTxt)
                .Text = varTxt(i)
                .Replacement.Text = Wks.Range(varRngAddress(i)).Value
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next i
        End With

    Next wdRng

    oDoc.SaveAs2 Environ("UserProfile") & "\desktop\002 Manual handling RA " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")

    If boolCloseAfterExec Then
        oDoc.Close
        oDoc.Parent.Quit
    End If

End Sub

Sub CopyPasteImage2(oDoc As Word.Document, Wks As Excel.Worksheet, Optional boolCloseAfterExec As Boolean = True)

    With oDoc
        .Activate

        .ActiveWindow.View = wdNormalView
        Wks.Range("K2:L15").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Bookmarks("CompanyLogo").Select
        .Parent.Selection.Paste
        .Parent.Selection.TypeParagraph

        Wks.Range("N10:O14").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        .Bookmarks("ConsulSig").Select
        .Parent.Selection.Paste
        .Parent.Selection.TypeParagraph

        .Save

        If boolCloseAfterExec Then
            oDoc.Close
            oDoc.Parent.Quit
        End If

    End With
End Sub

Sub CloseWord2(oDoc As Word.Document, Wks As Excel.Worksheet, Optional boolCloseAfterExec As Boolean = True)

    With oDoc
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `wdApp.Quit`

Comment: Add `wdApp.Quit` after `Call CloseWord2(wdDoc, Wks, False`

Answer (score 0):

Add `wdApp.Quit` after `Call CloseWord2(wdDoc, Wks, False)`

Your sub `CloseWord2` just saves and closes the Word Document, but nothing in your code closes the Word Application itself.

With `wdApp.Quit` you should be able to close the Word Application, but make sure you place it after you are done with Word!

Comment: Thanks for the help!